# Redirecting from one Javascript Function to a different Javascript Function in another script file

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller

So I have a function that is called when a button is pressed that redirects to a different view:

```
function direct(data) {
    window.location.href = "/Saved/Data";

}
```

It works as i expected it to. The issue I am having is that I need to do more Javascript work on the redirected page, but I have 2 separate script files. Is there a way to call a JS function after the redirect from the script that is linked with the other page, without having to press another button on the next page?

edit: 
The reason I am using separate Javascript files is because each page has a function that runs on the loading of the page, so I had to separate them.

Comment: Why not redirect straight to the last page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use query strings like `?data="hi"` and than read the url in the next file with `window.location`.

You can also use the local storage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: This worked. I was able put the data in the URL and retrieve it by grabbing from the url like so:  let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    var my = params.get("ID");                                                                                                             and the URL looked like: "/Saved/Data?ID=" + data